# How to get last ordered product details in Magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.2, order-success-page

am extending the onepage/success block and able to get the order id from it but what I want is last ordered information like Product URL, product ID, Product image and so, I did a search about this but I couldn't find any apt ans for this, any reference even would be helpful. 
I need all these info at success page.

> namespace Mobiweb\Ordershare\Block;
>
> class Ordershare extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success {
>     public function getOrder() {
>         return $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
>     }
>   }

in phtml
am getting last order id.
I want that last ordered product details by that id.

Comment: For all items of last order ?

Comment: I have updated the questions. @KishanPatadia

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    include('app/bootstrap.php');
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $orderId = 3; // Put your last orderId
    $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

    if(is_object($orderData) && $orderData->getId()!=''){
          $payment_info = (array)$orderData->getPaymentsCollection()->getData();
          $orderHistory = (array)$orderData->getStatusHistoryCollection()->getData();
          $items = $orderData->getAllItems();               
          $order_detail= (array)$orderData->getData();
          $billingData = (array)$orderData->getBillingAddress()->getData();
          $shippingData = (array)$orderData->getShippingAddress()->getData();

          // get each item detail
          foreach($items as $item){
              $item_detail = (array) $item->getData();
          }//end each

      }//end if

?>
```

Run this file, Print array as per your need